exception during call "spatial.addNode": no such property "longitude"
I use Neo4j 5.25 and write an application with Spring Data + Neo4j + Spatial extension.
I get an exception when calling spatial.addNode.
Created a pointLayer via migration.
CALL spatial.addPointLayer('wayPoints');

@Repository
public interface WayPointRepository extends Neo4jRepository<WayPoint, String> {

    @Query(value = """
            CREATE (w:WayPoint {parentId: $wayPoint.parentId, level:$wayPoint.level, latitude:$wayPoint.latitude, longitude:$wayPoint.longitude, tags: $wayPoint.tags})
            WITH w
            CALL spatial.addNode('wayPoints', w) YIELD node
            RETURN node
            """)
    void saveWithIndexation(@Param("wayPoint") WayPoint wayPoint);
}

The "saveWithIndexation" method must create a node and add it to the index (layer "wayPoints").
The structure of the query matches the example shown here.
https://neo4j.com/labs/neo4j-spatial/5/overview/introduction/
But I get an exception:
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Failed to invoke procedure spatial.addNode: Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: No such property, 'longitude'.
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:108) ~[neo4j-java-driver-5.23.0.jar:5.23.0-9b266bcb3c88c01e72d7c925b7c9647b45f5027d]
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalResult.blockingGet(InternalResult.java:109) ~[neo4j-java-driver-5.23.0.jar:5.23.0-9b266bcb3c88c01e72d7c925b7c9647b45f5027d]
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalResult.hasNext(InternalResult.java:51) ~[neo4j-java-driver-5.23.0.jar:5.23.0-9b266bcb3c88c01e72d7c925b7c9647b45f5027d]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DefaultNeo4jClient$DefaultRecordFetchSpec.one(DefaultNeo4jClient.java:443) ~[spring-data-neo4j-7.3.3.jar:7.3.3]
at java.base/java.util.Optional.flatMap(Optional.java:289) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate$DefaultExecutableQuery.lambda$getSingleResult$3(Neo4jTemplate.java:1279) ~[spring-data-neo4j-7.3.3.jar:7.3.3]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate$DefaultExecutableQuery.getSingleResult(Neo4jTemplate.java:1277) ~[spring-data-neo4j-7.3.3.jar:7.3.3]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.Neo4jQueryExecution$DefaultQueryExecution.execute(Neo4jQueryExecution.java:53) ~[spring-data-neo4j-7.3.3.jar:7.3.3]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.AbstractNeo4jQuery.execute(AbstractNeo4jQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-neo4j-7.3.3.jar:7.3.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:169) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:148) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:379) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy77.saveWithIndexation(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
But I specified such properties (longitude, latitude) in the query?
Can anyone tell me what the problem might be?
Thank you.
upd
here is my model
@Node("WayPoint")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class WayPoint {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;

    private String parentId;

    private WayPointLevel level;

    private Double latitude;

    private Double longitude;

    private List<String> tags;

}


Did you creaate the WayPoint class? If yes, can you show it?

Yes, of course.

Added to the description
